# Printing part of list starting from end and "loop" back to beginning not working

Tags: python-2.7

```
>>> mylist = [ 1, 2, 3 , 5, 'd']

>>> print 'mylist[-1:2] = ',mylist[-1:2]
```

output is an empty list: []

I am testing around with lists and from what I have so far understood from tutorials made me think the output would be `[d, 1, 2]`

Can anyone please help me out why isn't that the output?

Comment: Also, the output you think it would be would not be that, even if it worked. `x[2]` returns the 3rd value of the list, not the 2nd

Comment: no actually python would stop printing at STOP-1 inclusive, not STOP inclusive

Comment: or just "STOP exclusive" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why your code returns an empty list, it is important to note how accessing list elements in python works. Indexing with `:` on a python list (or slicing) works like this:

```
a_list[start:stop:step]
```

`stop` must always be greater than `start` for the list indexing/slicing to work.

When you access an element in the list by using a negative number as the index, say `a_list[-1]`, python adds the length of the list to it and gives you what you want. For ex:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a_list[-1] == a[5 - 1]
```

So when you do `mylist[-1:2]` it actually means `mylist[4:2]`. This violates `start` < `stop` condition. And hence returns an empty list.

This is what you are looking for:

```
[mylist[-1]] + mylist[:2]
```

Comment: +1 `mylist[-1:] + mylist[:2]` would be nicer and would work with any starting index.

Answer (score 0):

[Slicing does not work that way in python.](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.6/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) Instead, I suggest creating your own defined function, like below:

```
>>> def loop(list, start, end):
...     array = []
...     for k in range(start, end+1):
...             array.append(list[k])
...     return array
... 
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> desired_output = [5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> loop(x, -1, 2)
[5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> loop(x, -1, 2) == desired_output
True
>>>
```

This loops over the list, and adds each value of the list to another array, which it then returns.

Or, you can add them together using the following code:

```
[x[-1]] + x[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing with negative numbers (see [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.6/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)) does not make the list a ringbuffer. It's just another way of pointing to an element in the list. So, what you ask for is really: The list beginning at index 4 and ending at index 2. Doesn't make sense, hence you get nothing.